# What does the intonation pattern on "online" mean or imply?

Tags: american-english, speech, north-american-english, learning, intonation

What does the speaker mean or imply with the intonation on "[online](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/5838679.html)" at 0:31 around? A negative and doubtful query? Does the intonation pattern on "online" completely fall at the end? Or, does it slightly rise at the end because it occurs before a pause - intonation unit?

Comment: The speaker is expressing mockery or disbelief – a murder mystery online isn't of any interest to him. There is a slight interrogative lilt, but it isn't really a question. If any, "a murder mystery, online?" implies "Did I hear you right?"

Comment: Very relevant: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/why-cant-we-add-video-or-even-audio-clips-to-posts

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the speaker's tone, at least to me, seems to express derision and/or mockery of the concept of an online party.

A party, of course, is a gathering: an event where people come to a location in order to enjoy themselves with other people. When such an event takes place online, some elements of the event can be more awkward: everyone is in the same "room," so to speak, where chatting with a select group of people is much more difficult; people are prone to technical difficulties which limit their ability to participate in the event; people cannot share food or beverages with others; and so on.

Since the pandemic began, events have had to adapt to online environments, which, as I'm sure you've experienced, have a hard time surpassing that beloved human interaction. Plus, with the party being a *murder mystery* party, one would seemingly have to put on a costume only to sit in front of their computer the whole time. Obviously, this is not ideal. Some people, like the speaker, also probably find it awkward and/or strange to have such an event online in the first place.